# Users are not notified by email about a new document

Tags: google-drive

1. I have already shared a folder in Google docs across multiple users.
2. I create additional docs under the shared folder.
3. But the shared users don't get an email notification unless we add them again as collaborators to the new doc

How should we effectively collaborate in such circumstances?